# Bar over the entire width

Tags: html, css

Please see the website which i'm working on: LINK OFFLINE

I try to place the white bar over the entire width of the page. This worked well before he got centered vertically.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What was the code at that URL? The link is dead now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `width:100%` to the `#container` element.

Alternatively you can set `position:relative` on `#container` to accomplish the same effect (as [@mamadrood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10285325/128165) correctly noticed).

Comment: I can confirm this works, I just tested it.

Answer (score 2):

The #outer div is already absolute, #container should have a relative position.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you centered your element, it was set to `position: absolute;`. Absolutely positioned elements take up the dimensions of their children, so if you don't like that, you must specify a width.

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
}
```

or

```
#container {
    left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute` on your container element and you should be good.